How to compare arrays in Postgres
I am fairly new to Postgres, but so far I have been impressed with its array handling, but I have come across a problem that I am struggling to solve in any way that would be considered good.
I have a string array in a table, when that table is changed (trigger), I want to know what has changed in the array, for example:
The array before update is:  ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Sun"]
and after update: ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"]
So I want to know that "Sun" has been removed, and "Thu" & "Fri" has been added.
Note: Its not comparing two rows, but before and after data in a trigger.
Any assistance would be most gratefully received!

The solution will be different depending on whether you allow duplicate elements,consider their order to be significant and reordering to be a significant change you want to be informed about. Also, it's a bit easier with integers thanks to intarray extension, if the list of those strings is known and finite, and you can map each unique text string to an int.

My recommendation is not to use arrays as column types if you need to access elements inside the database.

It is an app that I have inherited, that is installed on thousands of clients, so changing the DB would be difficult.  There are no duplicates.  I could possibility map to integers and use 1-7 to represent the days of the week.  I will check if the intarray extension is available in supabase/postgres.
